# Promorule "Buy 3 Pay 2" does not apply

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, promotions, magento2.1.5, price-rules

I have to make some promo when you buy 3 items discount 1, and only pay 2, but when i try to buy the discount does not apply, this is my screenshot from the promo.

[image: magento 3 x 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition says that the product must be in all of the selected categories. Try changing that to:

Category **is one of**

Answer (score 0):

Aparently works, but its there some way to no affect the shipping, becouse the shipping table rates is "price (total) by destination" so the total are 59.97 thats mean 0 or free shiping, but the reality the client gone pay 39.98 thats mean the pay 10 $ for shipping.

[image]